# Redirecting Issue: Redirecting from one website to another

Tags: redirect

My problem is that I'm not able to redirect from one site to the other. I wish to be able to make my code go to one website for an instant and then redirect.

Here is the basic code:

```
  <button onclick="top.location.href = 'http://pub48.bravenet.com/passwd/logout.php?usernum=4049775127' 'http://infinitevideogames.weebly.com/';" target="_top">Logout</button>
```

How am I supposed to make the infinitevideogames.weebly.com link come right after.
Is there a way to make it go to that bravenet thing for an instant and then redirect to the infinite video games thing?

Comment: do you have a control over pub48.bravenet.com

Comment: I do not have control over that

Comment: so you want basically hit the logout on pub48 Site and redirect back to your site , right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have control over infinitevideogames.weebly.com to redirect back to your site and logout. If not you can use iframe and load the infinitevideogames for few seconds and javascript settimeout function to logout.

Comment: try this:

function logut_func(){
    window.location= 'logout link';
   }
function load_iframe_logout() {
      document.getElementById('MyFrame').src= 'link';
      setTimeout(logut_func,800);
      }